# ADF Application CSS ISSUE

Tags: css, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i have a major issue with my ADF Application since the day before. All went well 'till one point when out of the sudden this message popped-up in my Jdeveloper Console :

```
< org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.style.util.CSSUtils> < CSSUtils> < resolvePropertyValue> < URL_VALUE_EXPECTED_FOR_PROPERTY_IN_STYLE_SHEET>
```

I'm using WebLogic 12. I have no ideea how this happend. I did no change in the code. I started my pc to continue from where i left one day before and that happened. Now the application layout is messed up, CSS-wise, and i dont how to fix it!! Please help me! Has anyone else had this problem before?

Comment: Can you clarify if you see the message in Jdev or in the wls you deploy the app to? Have you tried to create a new app and see if this works?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom skin in your application?
Go into project properties->View and select one of the default skins (or change it in the trinidad-config.xml file manually).